# What happens when I'm casting an Linq to Entity query to ObjectQuery?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, objectquery

Simple question - what does this actually do?

```
var oq = (ObjectQuery<TEntity>)L2EQuery;
return ExecuteFirstorDefault<TEntity>(oq, MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

It's partly from the book Programming Entity Framework, by Julia Lerman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast itself does nothing more than check the type. Since your query is of type ObjectQuery<TEntity>, it succeeds. I presume ExecuteFirstOrDefault requires an argument of that type, hence the cast.